# Finitely generated projective $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$-Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, projective-module

I have to prove the following statement:

Let $d$ be a divisor of $n$. Then $\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$ is a projective $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$-Module $\iff$ $\text{gcd}(d, \frac{n}{d}) = 1$.

The implication $\impliedby$ follows by the chinese remainder theorem and the fact that projective $R$-Modules are direct summands of free $R$-Modules.

I'm having trouble with the implication $\implies$. Let $c = \frac{n}{d}$ and $N = \mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$ be a projective $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$-Module. Then there exists a $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$-Module $M$ s.t. $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \cong M \oplus N$ because $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is free over itself. By doing a change of basis via the canonical homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ we have $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \cong M \oplus N$ as abelian groups. Now this can only be the case if $M \cong \mathbb{Z}/c\mathbb{Z}$ because otherwise the LHS would be cyclic of order $n$ and the RHS would not. Hence $\text{gcd}(d,c) = 1$.

I was given the hint to use the FT of finitely generated abelian groups but I didn't use this here so I'm not really sure if my proof is correct, corrections and/or hints are appreciated.

From this I have to deduce that if $n = \prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{e_i}$ is the prime factor decomposition of $n$ then every finitely generated projective $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$-Module $M$ is of the form
$$\bigoplus_{i=1}^r (\mathbb{Z}/p_i^{e_i}\mathbb{Z})^{f_i}$$
with suitable $f_i \in \mathbb{N}_0$. I don't really see how this follows from the above statement? Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: For $\Rightarrow$, show that the surjection $\mathbb{Z}/(n)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/(d)$ splits.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Z}/(d)$ is projective we have $\mathbb{Z}/(n) \cong M \oplus \mathbb{Z}/(d)$ so the sequence $0 \to M \to \mathbb{Z}/(n) \to \mathbb{Z}/(d) \to 0$ splits, hence equivalently $\mathbb{Z}/(n) \to \mathbb{Z}/(d)$ splits.

Comment: Yes, exactly. What is $M$?

Comment: $M \cong \mathbb{Z}/(c)$ because otherwise $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$ has $n$ elements whereas $M \oplus \mathbb{Z}/(d)$ doesn't.

Comment: Yes. Can you now show that $c,d$ must be coprime?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand exactly why we needed the fact that $\mathbb{Z}/(n) \to \mathbb{Z}/(d)$ splits or where we need the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups?

Comment: FT is unnecessary for this part (although what is your argument why $\mathbb{Z}/(n) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/(c)\oplus\mathbb{Z}/(d)$?). It’s necessary for the next step, though, because it lets you reduce to the case of a projective $\mathbb{Z}/(p_i^{e_i})$-module, and then the case of $\mathbb{Z}/(p_i^k)$ with $k\leq e_i$.

Comment: If $c$,$d$ weren't coprime, then doing a change of Base we get $\mathbb{Z}/(n) \cong \mathbb{Z}/(c) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/(d)$ as abelian groups. But $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$ is cyclic and $\mathbb{Z}/(c) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/(d)$ isn't because $\text{gcd}(c,d) > 1$, a contradiction. Is this correct?

Comment: I think I know what you mean now: Since $\mathbb{Z}/(d)$ is projective and $\mathbb{Z}/(c)$ is a submodule of $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$ (because $c$ divides $n$), we get the exact sequence $0 \to \mathbb{Z}/(c) \to \mathbb{Z}/(n) \to \mathbb{Z}/(d) \to 0$ which splits, hence $\mathbb{Z}/(n) \cong \mathbb{Z}/(c) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/(d)$

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.